# How to serialize two forms and whole table

Tags: javascript, php, json, ajax

I tried to serialize two forms data and whole table together. The two form data working fine, but I couldn't serialize the whole table record. I attached the code, what I've tried so far below.

Can anyone help me to solve the problem?

**Form1**

```
<form class="form-horizontal" id="frmproduct">
  <div>
    <label>Total</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="totalcal" name="totalcal">
  </div>
  <div>
    <label>Subtotal</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="subtotal" name="subtotal">
  </div>
</form>
```

**Form2**

```
<form class="form-horizontal" id="frmvendor">
  <div>
    <label>vendor</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="vendor" name="vendor">
  </div>
  <div>
    <label>vendorn</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="vendorn" name="vendorn">
  </div>
</form>
```

**what is the error on this:?** `_data = $('#frmproduct,#frmvendor,table_data').serialize();`

**Table**

```
var table_data = [];
$('table tbody tr').each(function(row, tr) {
  var sub = {
    'productcode': $(tr).find('td:eq(0)').text(),
    'productname': $(tr).find('td:eq(1)').text(),
    'price': $(tr).find('td:eq(2)').text(),
    'qty': $(tr).find('td:eq(3)').text(),
    'total': $(tr).find('td:eq(4)').text(),

  };
  table_data.push(sub);
});
//  + "&table_data=" + table_data
_data = $('#frmproduct,#frmvendor,table_data').serialize();

var _method;
console.log(_data);
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "save.php",
  dataType: "JSON",
  data: {
    data: _data
  },
  success: function(data) {}
});
```

Comment: The problem is that you use "table_data" as CSS selector, so it is searching for <table_data> element.

Just see this but don't have solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't serialize an array of data the way you intend.

`$('#frmproduct,#frmvendor,table_data')` will search for the HTML elements with ids `frmproduct` and `frmvendor` and for an HTML element named `table_data`, but it will not magically include the JavaScript variable named `table_data` that you created.

Besides, [`.serialize()`](https://api.jquery.com/serialize/) is only meant to serialize form data.

---

For a possible solution, look into [`jQuery.param()`](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.param/) and append it to `_data`.

However, another problem is that your `table_data` is a complex array and not a simple object. You could try this:

```
_data = $('#frmproduct,#frmvendor').serialize();
_data += '&' + $.param( table_data );
```

but I'm not sure you will get the desired result. You probably have to restructure `table_data`.

Comment: only forms #frmproduct,#frmvendor working  table data not working how to send the table data to save.php page sir

Comment: @paypalkob Yes, that's what I have tried to explain in my answer: you CAN'T serialize `table_data` like that.

Comment: then how to send the table data to save.php page any other way

Comment: i tried sir result displayed undefined   any other way to write the table and get the value sir.